# Recommendations on Intermediate Level Probability/Applied Statistics Book

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, book-recommendation, applications, decision-theory

So I'm an Internal Medicine Resident with an interest in mathematics and I have a BS in physics and MS in math. Lately I've been getting more into the statistical interpretation of diagnostic test, signs, and symptoms and the application to clinical reasoning. I would like to have a better fundamental understanding of how it affects clinical reasoning. I understand a little of probability through the lens of quantum mechanics, however I haven't really studied higher level statistics as I mostly focused on geometry/topology.

So essentially my question is what would be some good intermediate level resources/books on probability theory? I think ideally it would be something with an applied bent as well, and maybe some exposure to decision theory.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: Why off-topic, if there is even a tag for “book-recommendation”?

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful at the level of presentation you want, with lots of worked examples in Python also.

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-18545-9